# Haskell's "where" usage

Tags: haskell

I am doing an exercise of fp-course:
https://github.com/system-f/fp-course/blob/5e0848b4eacb3ddff65553ab5beb6447b73f61b3/src/Course/Applicative.hs#L77

Correct answer is

```
  (<*>) fs as = foldRight (\f bs -> foldRight (\a bs -> f a :. bs) Nil as ++ bs) Nil fs
```

I trying to take the inner `foldRight` into `where` sub sentence, an error occurred.

```
  (<*>) fs as = foldRight (\f bs -> f as ++ bs) Nil fs
                  where f as = foldRight (\a bs -> f a :. bs) Nil as
```

The error is

```
src/Course/Applicative.hs:75:53: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘a’ with ‘List a’
      Expected: List (List a -> List b)
        Actual: List (a -> b)
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          (<*>) :: forall a b. List (a -> b) -> List a -> List b
        at src/Course/Applicative.hs:(70,5)-(72,13)
    • In the third argument of ‘foldRight’, namely ‘fs’
      In the expression: foldRight (\ f bs -> f as ++ bs) Nil fs
      In an equation for ‘<*>’:
          (<*>) fs as
            = foldRight (\ f bs -> f as ++ bs) Nil fs
            where
                f as = foldRight (\ a bs -> f a :. bs) Nil as
    • Relevant bindings include
        as :: List a (bound at src/Course/Applicative.hs:75:12)
        fs :: List (a -> b) (bound at src/Course/Applicative.hs:75:9)
        (<*>) :: List (a -> b) -> List a -> List b
          (bound at src/Course/Applicative.hs:73:3)
   |
75 |   (<*>) fs as = foldRight (\f bs -> f as ++ bs) Nil fs
   |                                                     ^^

src/Course/Applicative.hs:76:25: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘t1’ with ‘List t1’
      Expected: t1 -> t2
        Actual: List t1 -> List t2
      ‘t1’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the inferred type of f :: t1 -> t2
        at src/Course/Applicative.hs:76:25-68
    • In an equation for ‘<*>’:
          (<*>) fs as
            = foldRight (\ f bs -> f as ++ bs) Nil fs
            where
                f as = foldRight (\ a bs -> f a :. bs) Nil as
      In the instance declaration for ‘Applicative List’
    • Relevant bindings include
        f :: t1 -> t2 (bound at src/Course/Applicative.hs:76:25)
   |
76 |                   where f as = foldRight (\a bs -> f a :. bs) Nil as
   |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Failed, 10 modules loaded.
```

How to take inner `foldRight` into `where`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're binding the name `f` to the functions from the input list, it's a pretty bad idea to name your local function also `f`! The effect of this is actually that you're not using your function at all, because its definition is shadowed by the lambda binding `\f bs -> ...`. Just call it something like `innerFold`.

Talking of shadowing, there's no need to make `as` an argument to this function because `as` is already in scope anyway. It means you'll have two variables called `as` which just happen to always have the same value. Don't do this.

You *do* however need to make `f` an argument of this function, because that is only bound in the lambda of the outer fold:

```
  fs<*>as = foldRight (\f bs -> innerFold f ++ bs) Nil fs
   where innerFold f = foldRight (\a bs -> f a :. bs) Nil as
```

Note that the `++ bs` is unnecessary and inefficient here. You only need that because the inner fold always piles its results onto `Nil`, but better is to just pile onto the outer `bs` straight away, this way you avoid that each chunk needs to be traversed again for appending:

```
  fs<*>as = foldRight (\f bs -> innerFold f bs) Nil fs
   where innerFold f bs = foldRight (\a cs -> f a :. cs) bs as
```

...which can be eta-reduced

```
  fs<*>as = foldRight innerFold Nil fs
   where innerFold f bs = foldRight (\a cs -> f a :. cs) bs as
```

or shorter

```
  fs<*>as = foldRight innerFold Nil fs
   where innerFold f bs = foldRight (\a -> (f a :.)) bs as
```

or even

```
  fs<*>as = foldRight innerFold Nil fs
   where innerFold f bs = foldRight ((:.) . f) bs as
```

(not necessarily recommended.)

Comment: I believe your suggested code does `foldRight (\ a bs -> f a :. bs) Nil as as`, specifically applying to `as` twice.

Comment: Forgot to remove the argument.